# Sqoop import issue

Tags: oracle, hadoop

I am importing a table into hive. So i have created a external table on hadoop and import data from oracle using sqoop. but the problem is when i am querying data all columns are into one column in hive.

Table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `default.dba_cdr_head`(
  `BI_FILE_NAME` varchar(50),
  `BI_FILE_ID` int,
  `UPDDATE` TIMESTAMP)
LOCATION
  'hdfs:/tmp/dba_cdr_head';
```

Sqoop:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.XX.XX:15xx:CALLS \
--username username\
--password password \
--table CALLS.DBM_CDR_HEAD \
--columns "BI_FILE_NAME, BI_FILE_ID, UPDDATE" \
--target-dir /tmp/dba_cdr_head \
--hive-table default.dba_cdr_head
```

data looks like as below:

```
hive> select * from dba_cdr_head limit 5;
OK
CFT_SEP0801_20120724042610_20120724043808M,231893,      NULL    NULL
CFT_SEP1002_20120724051341_20120724052057M,232467,      NULL    NULL
CFT_SEP1002_20120724052057_20120724052817M,232613,      NULL    NULL
CFT_SEP0701_20120724054201_20120724055154M,232904,      NULL    NULL
CFT_SEP0601_20120724054812_20120724055853M,233042,      NULL    NULL
Time taken: 3.693 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed table create option (    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',') and it solved.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `default.dba_cdr_head`(
  `BI_FILE_NAME` varchar(50),
  `BI_FILE_ID` int,
  `UPDDATE` TIMESTAMP)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION
  'hdfs:/tmp/dba_cdr_head';
```